# Increasing svg circle stroke-width brings down inner circle size

Tags: css, svg

My understanding is, svg circle with `stroke-width` renders two concentric circles (or a doughnut like image) with its internal radius as `r` and its external radius as `r plus stroke-width`.

It looks like,
[image]

But, as one can see when the stroke-width increases from 4 to 24, the inner circle has become smaller?

Plunker code is [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/jqbIpv6GbVJLsSivLwBZ?p=preview).
So, what is wrong with the formula,

```
external radius = r + stroke-width
```

More importantly, why does inner circle size depend on stroke width?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid your understanding is wrong.

An SVG circle with [stroke-width](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html#StrokeProperty) renders two concentric circles (or a doughnut like image) with its internal radius as r - ½ the stroke width and its external radius as r + ½ stroke-width.

Comment: That's not true in chrome browsers.